# Backbone - What is the best way to listen to 2 models?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working on a project and I was curious as to what is the best way to listen to 2 objects that are used in the same function?

For example:

```
this.model1 = someModel();
this.model2 = someModel();

this.listenTo(this.model1, "sync", this.someFunction); // how can I get listenTo to listen for both changes before calling the function?
this.listenTo(this.model2, "sync", this.someFunction);

someFunction: function() {
    this.sumValue = (this.model1.get('value') + this.model2.get('value));
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The simplest way might be using a counter counting to 2 in `this.someFunction`. A more sophisticated implementation would pass `this.someFunction` to the `this.listenTo` statements wrapped by a functional wrapper working a semaphore waiting for 2 calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a base model and inherit from your other models:

```
    var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        // ToDo
    });

    var FileModel = DataModel.extend({
        // ToDo
    });

    var FolderModel = DataModel.extend({
        // ToDo
    });
```

Make the model type of the collection same base model:

```
    var DataCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: DataModel
    });
```

Comment: How does this enable one to trigger a function after two different model instances are synced? Some explanation would be nice...